# Frame active, but setting visible to false = nullpointer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So i have a bit of a weird issue, i just posted and fixed my other error, but that seems to have created this one, and it makes no sense.

Basically, the user presses a button, this window opens, then whether he presses cancel, or register, this window should setVisible to false. but when this code gets executed, it says my window is null.

```
package frontend;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Registration extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static boolean ranOnce = false;

private JPanel contentPane;
private Registration reg;
private JTextField userTF;
private JTextField passTF;
private JTextField emailTF;

private LoginProcess lp = new LoginProcess();
private JLabel error;
private JButton cancelBtn;

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Registration() {
    if (!ranOnce) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    reg = new Registration();
                    reg.setVisible(true);
                    ranOnce = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 245, 212);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:");
    lblUsername.setBounds(10, 11, 75, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblUsername);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
    lblPassword.setBounds(10, 36, 75, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblPassword);

    JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("Email:");
    lblEmail.setBounds(10, 61, 75, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblEmail);

    userTF = new JTextField();
    userTF.setBounds(95, 8, 130, 20);
    contentPane.add(userTF);
    userTF.setColumns(10);

    passTF = new JTextField();
    passTF.setColumns(10);
    passTF.setBounds(95, 33, 130, 20);
    contentPane.add(passTF);

    emailTF = new JTextField();
    emailTF.setColumns(10);
    emailTF.setBounds(95, 58, 130, 20);
    contentPane.add(emailTF);

    error = new JLabel("");
    error.setBounds(10, 154, 215, 14);
    contentPane.add(error);

    JButton regBtn = new JButton("Register");
    regBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (!userTF.getText().equals("") || !passTF.getText().equals("") || !emailTF.getText().equals("")) {
                try {
                    if (lp.newUser(userTF.getText(), passTF.getText(), emailTF.getText())) {
// THIS IS LINE 117                         reg.setVisible(false);
                        Main.mainFrame.setVisible(true);
                    } else {
                        if (lp.duplicateAccount) {
                            error.setText("Error: Username already in use.");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {

                }
            }
        }
    });

    regBtn.setBounds(10, 120, 215, 23);
    contentPane.add(regBtn);

    cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancelBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            reg.setVisible(false);
            Main.mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    cancelBtn.setBounds(10, 86, 215, 23);
    contentPane.add(cancelBtn);

}

}
```

this is the abnormal error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at frontend.Registration$3.actionPerformed(Registration.java:117)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
```

i really have no clue as to why it's saying my window is null, when it's not. it has to be something i've done when initialising the window.

Comment: can you point us to the line?

Comment: What is line no `117` ?

Comment: Sorry, should've clarified. It's:

reg.setVisible(false);

Comment: @JoelWMale: Use the "edit" link to put a comment pointing to that line, e.g. `// <================ This is line 117`

Comment: Will do @T.J.Crowder. Ruchira i am aware it is null, but my problem is i can't figure out why it is null. It should not be, as i initialised it at the start.

Comment: Woah, wait a minute, what are you trying to achieve in that constructor? If it hasn't run before, run the same constructor again later? And assign to a field called `reg`. Whatever you are trying to achieve, do it before the constructor, it's too late otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is it not working ?**

You are not using *Singleton* design pattern correctly. Did you notice that you have two `JFrame` popping up ?

```
if (!ranOnce)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()//this call the run method in a separate thread
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    // for the current instance of Registration, you are setting
                    // the reg variable by calling another instance of Registration => thats not the correct way to do a Singleton
                    reg = new Registration(); 
                    reg.setVisible(true);
                    ranOnce = true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

So, let's assume you are calling `new Registration()` in your main method, you will enter the `public Registration()` constructor (let's call it instance1) and set the variable `reg` by calling one more time the constructor `new Registration()` (instance2) but by this time, `ranOnce` will be `true` and so `EventQueue.invokeLater` will not be called => `reg` will not be set in instance2 => `NullPointerException` when clicking on `Jbutton` in the second frame (the one on the top) (instance2). Clicking on first frame (instance1) button's will hide the second frame (instance2).

**How to fix it ?**

Use a proper *Singleton* :

```
private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

private static boolean      ranOnce             = false;

private JPanel              contentPane;
private static Registration     reg;
private JTextField          userTF;
private JTextField          passTF;
private JTextField          emailTF;
private LoginProcess lp = new LoginProcess();
private JLabel              error;
private JButton             cancelBtn;




public static synchronized Registration getRegistration()
{
    if(reg == null)
        reg = new Registration();

    return reg;


}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
private Registration()
{


    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 245, 212);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:");
    lblUsername.setBounds(10, 11, 75, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblUsername);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
    lblPassword.setBounds(10, 36, 75, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblPassword);

    JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("Email:");
    lblEmail.setBounds(10, 61, 75, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblEmail);

    userTF = new JTextField();
    userTF.setBounds(95, 8, 130, 20);
    contentPane.add(userTF);
    userTF.setColumns(10);

    passTF = new JTextField();
    passTF.setColumns(10);
    passTF.setBounds(95, 33, 130, 20);
    contentPane.add(passTF);

    emailTF = new JTextField();
    emailTF.setColumns(10);
    emailTF.setBounds(95, 58, 130, 20);
    contentPane.add(emailTF);

    error = new JLabel("");
    error.setBounds(10, 154, 215, 14);
    contentPane.add(error);

    JButton regBtn = new JButton("Register");
     regBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (!userTF.getText().equals("") || !passTF.getText().equals("") || !emailTF.getText().equals("")) {
                    try {
                        if (lp.newUser(userTF.getText(), passTF.getText(), emailTF.getText())) {
                        setVisible(false);
                            Main.mainFrame.setVisible(true);
                        } else {
                            if (lp.duplicateAccount) {
                                error.setText("Error: Username already in use.");
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException e) {

                    }
                }
            }
        });

    regBtn.setBounds(10, 120, 215, 23);
    contentPane.add(regBtn);

    cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancelBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
             setVisible(false);

        }
    });
    cancelBtn.setBounds(10, 86, 215, 23);
    contentPane.add(cancelBtn);



}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Registration registration = Registration.getRegistration();
    registration.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I completely understood it, however using your code did not seem to work. Pressing the button to open this code, just did nothing. no error, but no Jframe was shown.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much! Huge headache gone. I won't ever make that mistake again >_>

Answer (score 0):

Try `setVisible(fasle)` instead of `reg.setVisible(false)`